# Python flask query parámetros

Tags: python, sql, flask

Estoy pasando 2 txt parámetros a la API de la sig.manera: Params=p1+p2, y los recupero en la API cómo substrings. Me funciona bien, pero me pregunto si es la mejor manera de hacerlo. Me pregunto también, cual es la mejor manera de pasar una lista y como recibirla en la API. Soy nuevo en Python. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Comment: Investiga sobre JSON

Comment: Tu pregunta se basa en una opinión y no refleja que tengas un problema o error con el codigo actual. Si buscas opiniones sobre optimizacion de igual manera debes demostrar cual es tu código actual ([repro]) así como el resultado esperado (una respuesta por parte del api, o la reduccion del tiempo de respuesta del api o procesamiento de la funcion)

Answer (score 0):

Si la petición es de tipo POST o PUT, lo correcto sería que el parámetro fuera en el cuerpo de la petición, en forma de JSON, en vez de ir en la URL. En el cuerpo no tienes problema para enviar listas, diccionarios, o cualquier tipo de dato json. En este caso el cliente enviaría un json que puede contener por ejemplo `[1, 2, 3]`.

Desde Flask accederías a ese contenido por ejemplo así:

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/mi_ruta", methods=["POST"])
def mi_funcion(): # La función no necesita parámetros en este caso
   lista = request.get_json()
```

Naturalmente habría que hacer un código más robusto para verificar que efecivamente se ha recibido un json válido dentro de la `request` y no sólo que sea válido, sino que sea lo que se espera (una lista). Para este tipo de cosas es de ayuda la librería Pydantic.

Si en cambio la petición es de tipo GET, en ese caso no puede llevar cuerpo, por lo que no queda más remedio que recibir la lista en la URL. Aquí lo habitual es recibirlo en la query, que es lo que va tras un signo `?` y tiene la forma general `parametro=valor`. El valor en este caso podría ser una cadena con la lista.

El cliente enviaría algo como `GET /mi_ruta?lista=[1,2,3]` aunque naturalmente hará uso de la recodificación necesaria para que la URL tenga solo caracteres permitidos, por lo que enviará posiblemente algo como `GET /mi_ruta?lista=%5B1,2,3%5D` pero eso no importa porque Flask lo decodificará de nuevo al recibirlo.

En tu función puedes acceder a la query y obtenerla como cadena, por lo que luego podrás procesarla en Python

```py
import json
from flask import request

@app.route("/mi_ruta", methods=["GET"])
def mi_funcion(): # La función no necesita parámetros en este caso
   lista_str = request.args.get('lista')
   lista = json.loads(lista_str)
   return str(lista)
```